# How to get Scrapy to parse CSS

Tags: scrapy

I am following [this guide](https://hexfox.com/p/scrape-your-cinemas-listings-to-get-a-daily-email-of-films-with-a-high-imdb-rating/) to scrape movie titles from my local cinema website. I am using Scrapy Spider and CSS parsing to get this done. Within the HTML for the site, each movie title is constructed like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 movie-description">
    <h2>Minions: The Rise of Gru<h2>
        ...
```

Here is my code that attempts to  scrape this info

```
import scrapy

class CinemaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cinema"
    allowed_domains = ["cannonvalleycinema10.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://cannonvalleycinema10.com/"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        movie_names = response.css(".col-md-12.movie-description h2::text").extract()
        for movie_name in movie_names:
            yield {
                'name': movie_name
            }
```

The cinema's website is [here](https://cannonvalleycinema10.com/). I have tried all sorts of different combinations for what would get the titles I'm looking for to be added to my json file but can't figure it out.

If it helps, I am running this code:

```
scrapy runspider .\cinema_scrape.py -o movies.json
```

I am in the proper directory, too.

Comment: It isn't working because the content you are trying to scrape is rendered in an iframe and also generated by javascript.  You will need to use selenium or something similar in order to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

The page is dynamically loaded so you have try `scrapy and json` together :

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy import FormRequest
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    import json
    from scrapy.http import Request
    
    class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'test'
        url = 'https://cabbtheatres.intensify-solutions.com/embed/ajaxGetRepertoire'
    
        cookies = {
            'PHPSESSID': 'i8l12572hvd3a702d4nfj3vbg0',
        }
    
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            # 'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=i8l12572hvd3a702d4nfj3vbg0',
            'Origin': 'https://cabbtheatres.intensify-solutions.com',
            'Referer': 'https://cabbtheatres.intensify-solutions.com/embed?location=3663456',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        }
    
        data = {
            'location': '3663456',
            'date': '2022-07-30',
            'lang': 'en',
            'soon': '',
        }
    
    
        def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url =self.url,
                method='POST',
                formdata=self.data,
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse_item,
            )
    
        def parse_item(self, response):
            detail=response.json()
            titles=detail['data']
            for name in titles:
                title=name['title']
                print(title)
```

output:

```
Minions: The Rise of Gru
Thor Love and Thunder
DC League of Super-Pets
Elvis(2022)
Mrs. Harris Goes to Paris
Where the Crawdads Sing
Top Gun: Maverick
Nope
```